# django2 vs django3 how to write path instead of url

Tags: python, django, url, path, tags

so I'm trying to type this in django3 with path

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', TagIndexView.as_view(), name='tagged')
```

I tried tag/slug but I guess it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe here is the regex of the `<slug:…>` path converter, you can thus implement this with:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('tag/<slug:slug>/', TagIndexView.as_view(), name='tagged')
]
```

or you can keep using the regex with [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path):

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', TagIndexView.as_view(), name='tagged')
]
```